# accumulating occurances of a "true" or "1" result in a separate column

Tags: vba, loops, accumulate

I have about 100 rows that include a random number generator in a column and in another column with calulations=A based on that random number and other things.  I have set up a column with an if statement to examine if A is within an upper and lower range which returns a "1" if true (a hit, if you will) and "0" if not. I want to run a loop and count the number of hits over time in these cells.  Essentially i need a column that acccumulates the results so in the end I can see what range has the most hits, etc.

Comment: I don't think so. countif will equal 1 when A is 1 but go back to 0 on the next loop.  I need the cell to accumulate so the first time A is 1, the cell equals 1, next time A is 1, the cell equals 2, etc.....

Comment: Loop over your 100 cells, and if there's a 1, add 1 to an adjacent cell.  It's not clear though what you mean by "over time" - what's triggering a recalculation?

Comment: Thank Tim, I will try that.  I was using a goal seek to loop it.  but could use the macro.  the random numbers recalculate on any sheet auto-calculation, so I am attempting to the results of every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simpler, let's first say your data is stored as follows, before we start, on your worksheet "ws":

```
     A              | B                | C
1    Random Numbers | Calculated Value | Accumulated Value
2    0              | 1                | 
3    5              | 0                | 
4    8              | 1                | 
5    73             | 0                | 
6    2              | 0                | 

[...]
```

And let's say we want to run this process 10,000 times to see which rows get the highest accumulated values, represented as the sum of the calculated value from each of the previous iterations. I would suggest the following VBA solution:

```
Sub AccumulateValues
    Dim MaxIterations As Long: MaxIterations = 10000        
    Dim curRow as Long, LastRow as Long, it as Long

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'Required to set it to manual

    With ws
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For it = 1 to MaxIterations

            'Force the Recalculation of Cells in columns A and B:
            Application.Calculate

            For curRow = 2 To LastRow                    
                'Sum the result of this iteration with the accumulated value 
                'until the previous iteration and stores it.
                ws.Cells(curRow, 3) = ws.Cells(curRow, 3) + ws.Cells(curRow, 2)    

            Next curRow
        Next it

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio, I copied and tweaked to start to operate on row 8 and sum cells in the (curRow, 12 and 13).  When I run it I get error 424 Object Expected.  Seems like it can't get past first two lines.

Comment: As usual, I am very frustrated at myself for not understanding the meanings of the error because I don't understand fully the language rules.  I tried disabling a few things and even changing the variables to absolute and disabling the Dim line.  I get different errors depending on what I do, but It is not showing me were the code broke in the debug so I can zero in on the problem.  I even changed the worksheet name to "ws" and the filename too!

Comment: @Tommister, it might be a reference error. When I meant to refer to your worksheet as ws, it can be whatever name you choose it to be. Let's say it's named "Sheet1". Try adding this before the With:
Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").

Else, you can just replace the line "With ws" to: With ActiveSheet.

Comment: If not, try running it in VBA step-by-step (by pressing F8) and please do return to report in which line it stopped working.

Comment: Did you try the suggested solution, @Tommister? Any progress?